# Kusto external table displays 2001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 for cell that has value 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, external-tables

This is the value of the column in the csv:
01/01/0001 00:00:00

The external table value for this column is:
2001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000

Column is defined in the kql as: lastModifiedDate: datetime.

Any reason why this is happening and how to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to avoid dates issues, and that is working with ISO format.
https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html

Other formats depend on culture, environment settings and libraries implementation, e.g.:
***01/02/30*** might be interpreted ***1st of February*** or ***2nd of January***, while the year might be interpreted as ***1930*** or ***2030***.

When using the ISO format everything is definitive, E.g.:
***1930-02-01*** can be only interpreted in one way, ***1st of February, 1930***